# got error message: import.php: Missing parameter: import_type when trying to upload large sql file

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a sql file(507MB) through phpmyadmin(which allows to upload 512 MB), after around 2 hours, I got error message:

```
import.php: Missing parameter: import_type
import.php: Missing parameter: format
```

what could be the problem? what should I do?

Comment: Are you using a subdomain or www?

Comment: the database is on subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your php.ini file. 
Increase the upload_max_filesize to a bigger number and restart your Apache webserver.

I thought ( not sure) that by default the upload filesize for mysql was 2MB.
Try to increase that number.

Comment: upload_max_filesize: 10MB, how could I increase it? I can access cpanel, but how could I restart apache webserver?

Comment: Do you have root access? If you do not have root access you should contact your host company and ask them to increase that value. @user2507818

Answer (score 0):

follow this

ssh your machine.

```
vi /etc/php.ini

upload_max_filesize = 2M

upload_max_filesize = xxM [give your value]
```

sample value

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

save it

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

it will work